# Powershell Remove-Item keeps empty files

Tags: powershell

So I have a powershell script and at the very end I'm doing this:

```
if (Test-Path $xxx -pathType container) { Remove-Item $xxx -Force -Recurse }
```

The directory usually has 30-40 files and maybe some other subdirs. It removes *most* of them, but keeps some files (and maybe subdirs too) there with size of 0 byte. So basically it doesn't use up any space anymore, but the directory with some empty files is still there.

Any idea how to remove the directory fully without leaving empty files there?

Thanks!

Comment: probably a stray process handle that needs to be unlocked before you can delete them.   Handle.exe from sysinternals can tell us if this is the case.

Comment: You can test that without needing a third-party program with        Try{[io.file]::OpenWrite($file)} Catch {"File $file is open."}

Comment: Do you have permission to the files? Are they stored on the local filesystem or on a UNC path perhaps? Are you getting any error messages from `Remove-Item`?

Comment: Its on local filesystem. I've tried the script on a much slower machine and there was an error message saying the directory is not empty therefore Remove-Item cant delete it. I don't really understand why though, -Recurse is set.

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using?  Prior to V4 the -Recurse parameter of Remove-Item doesn't work properly.

Comment: I'm guessing it's version 2, I'll try to update to version 4 and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Version 4 is the same. Still not clearing the whole directory, leaving 0 byte files there.

Comment: what happens when you use 'del.exe' instead of Remove-Item, try the `/F /S /Q` parameters